# Is reusing CUDA kernel possible?

Tags: cuda

I need to the following task in CUDA.

> > Launch the kernel
> >
> > Inside kernel do some task and wait
> >
> > Program continues in the main program after the kernel launch
> >
> > Program wants to signal the kernel threads to proceed further
> >
> > Kernel threads upon receiving the signal from host, proceeds execution of further code.

Is this even possible in CUDA?.

Comment: It's possible. It's not necessarily a good idea, however…it depends…

Comment: Just save your data on the GPU and launch a second kernel later

Comment: Yes, its possible.  If you do some research on "persistent kernels" you will find some examples.

Answer (score 2):

Without any details on the purpose, that looks like a terrible idea.

You will keep GPU ressources in use while not using them. First thing to consider would be to rethink your design to avoid the need to split GPU work, if possible. If not, then just run two kernels.